# How can I start my cells in a tableview lower?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a quick mock of an app and I wanted to start the cells in my table view lower. [image: Image of tabelview] If you look at the image I want the cells to start lower than they are currently.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking for adding offset from top on the Table View. If that is the case, you can use contentOffset property on table view as below:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```